# I will used qt 5.8.0 & webview added in project. i.e QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView: No such file or directory

Tags: qt, webview, qt5

/home/nadim/Error in " Util.asciify("build-qt-pro-1-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_GCC_64bit-Profile")": TypeError: Property 'asciify' of object Core::Internal::UtilsJsExtension(0x1dd1d10) is not a function/ui_mainwindow.h:13: error: QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView: No such file or directory
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>

Libraries added But till this Error will occur  , Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it:

> No such file or directory #include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>

You will need to add this if you are using qmake:

```
QT += webview
```

For this issue:

> TypeError: Property 'asciify' ...

You need to check your kit configuration if using QtCreator or alternatively, `[this][1]` may also help.